# Proving that a sequence is Cauchy (sequence including factorials).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${s_n}$ be a sequence such that
${s_n}=1+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}$

Prove that ${s_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

My work thus far:

$|s_m-s_n|$=$|1+\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+...+\frac{1}{(n+k)!}-1-\frac{1}{2!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}|<\epsilon$

$=\frac{1}{(n+k)!}+...$

Now, this this possible(?):

Given $\epsilon>0$ and letting $m,n>n_0, m=n+k$ I'm going to a choose $n_0$ such that $\frac{1}{(n+k)!}<\epsilon$, so I'm choosing $n_0>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ assuming that $n_0=m+n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is that $m=n+k$, you need to say so; as it is, you never defined $k$, so the expressions involving $k$ are meaningless. And if $m=n+k$, your calculation is incorrect:

$$|s_m-s_n|=s_m-s_n=\frac1{(n+1)!}+\frac1{(n+2)!}+\ldots+\frac1{(n+k)!}\;,$$

not just the last term of that sum.

HINT: $0<s_{n+1}\le\frac12s_n$ for all $n\ge 1$, and it’s easy to show that a geometric sequence with ratio $\frac12$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I didn't understand the 'Hint' until a minute ago, thank you!

Comment: @sillyme: You’re welcome!