# Show that the sequence $1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence $1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$ is Cauchy.
I'm not sure where to start with this problem, I know that if I can show that the sequence is convergent I can manipulate the inequality definition of the limit to have $|X_m-X_n|<\epsilon$ but I don't get how to prove the limit exists.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to prove that $x\_n=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$ is a Cauchy sequence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455997/how-to-prove-that-x-n-1-frac12-cdots-frac1n-is-a-cauchy-sequence). Also duplicates [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498089/proving-that-a-sequence-is-cauchy-sequence-including-factorials/498092#498092), whose accepted answer just offers a hint.

Comment: It converges by monotone convergence and boundedness, hence Cauchy.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry for posting a duplicate question. How can I remove my question?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $x_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!}$ and $m<n.$ Then $x_n-x_m=\displaystyle\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{k!}\le\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$. This is a geometric sum.